# Storing Checkbox value in a Property Wix 3.7

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wix3.7

Currently I am working on a simple project in which i have to modify an xml file using user input in WIX 3.7. Everything goes fine except in case of checkbox.
I have created a Property and then using that property in a checkbox type of control. I need that if the checkbox is checked then Node value will be modified to 1 and if not then 0.
Below is the code i have used.

```
<Property Id="ISPATH" Secure="yes"></Property>

<Control Id="checkBox1" Type="CheckBox" Height="18" Width="67" X="104" Y="108" Text="Is-Path" Property="ISPATH"  CheckBoxValue="1" >
      </Control>

<util:XmlFile Id="ModifyPath" Action="setValue" Permanent="yes" ElementPath="/DataBaseSettings/IsPath" 
             File="[#Settings]" Value="[ISPATH]" SelectionLanguage="XSLPattern" Sequence="1" />
```

No Change is seen in ISPATH property.

Any Suggestions????

Comment: Have you tried a SelectionLanguage of XPath instead of XSLPattern, also check that /DataBaseSettings is at the root of your xml file.

Comment: It works using XPath. Thanks......